# Executor Lost error when trying to insert data from a temp table to hive partitioned table dynamically

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive, etl

I am trying to insert data to a hive partitioned table dynamically

Approach 1:

Using spark sql `insert into table` query method and I get `Executor Lost` error even for a very small size of data (5K records). Here I am first reading data from a hive table using Spark then creating a temporary table out of it and then trying to insert data from temporary table to hive partitioned table dynamically.

Approach 2:
Using Spark API
`df.partitionBy("date").saveAsTable("table")` method it doesn't throw any error for 500K records.

I am running the spark application in yarn-client mode.

In both cases I have used same resource allocation in spark-submit command.

Could you please explain what's wrong with approach 1 ?

I expect approach 1 to work without any error.

Comment: You need to add more details about approach 1 like from where you are reading the data for insert. Also share example codes for both approach with full error trace for first approach.